# How do we find path with largest bottleneck capacity?

Tags: algorithm

I'm referring to the notes here: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs473/sp2011/Lectures/17_notes.pdf
On the last page and last topic, it mentions we can do a binary search to find the path with largest bottleneck capacity. But I'm having trouble of understanding the intuition behind this, what is a good way to start an approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]  and read the information guides in the help center [help]. Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a path from *s* to *t* with bottleneck capacity >= *C* if you can connect *s* to *t* using only edges that have capacity >= *C*.

The binary search means:

```
sort edges in E by capacity
let lo=0,hi=|E|
while lo < hi
    mid = (lo+hi)/2
    if you can connect s to t using only edges > E[mid] (use e.g., BFS for this)
        lo=mid+1
    else
        hi=mid

result = E[mid].capacity
```

It takes O(log N) iterators, and each iteration takes O(N) time in the BFS, for a total of O(N log N).  The sort is also O(N log N), of course.

I would probably use Kruskal's algorithm for this, instead:  process edges in descending capacity order and stop when *s* connects to *t*.